# Handling back button operation in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have 1 activity .Inside that activity I have 4 fragments .If I switch between those fragments I want to handle my backtrack.
If I'm at any fragment I have to go directly to the main activity on pressing the back button once. Once I reach at home activity and if I again press the back button the activity should get closed.

The below is my home activity

```
package com.fuzail.my_app.DatabaseSQLite;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.fuzail.my_app.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

import static android.content.DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE;
import static android.content.DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE;
import static com.fuzail.my_app.Constant.NO;
import static com.fuzail.my_app.Constant.YES;

public class MaccabiDrawerHome extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private Menu menu;
    NavigationView navView;
    private ArrayList<UserModel> list = new ArrayList<UserModel>();
    private int currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay;
    private SharedPreferenceMaccabi mSharedPreference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_home);

        Fragment fragment = new FragViewProfile();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                add(R.id.content_frame, fragment).
                commit();

        // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.macaabi_myprofile_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_maccabi_menu);
        toolbar.setTitle("My Profile");
        // Find our drawer view
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_maccabi);
        navView = findViewById(R.id.maccabi_navigation);
        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        mSharedPreference = SharedPreferenceMaccabi.getInstance(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MaccabiDrawerHome.class);

        FragViewProfile test = (FragViewProfile) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);

        if (test != null && test.isVisible()) {
            finish();
        }
        else {
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        String title = "";
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.mallmemb:
                fragment = new FragAllMembers();
                toolbar.setTitle("All Members");
                menu.findItem(R.id.item_cal).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.item_edit).setVisible(false);
                break;
            case R.id.mlikes:
                fragment = new FragLikes();
                ((FragLikes) fragment).getAllLikedByData(list);
                toolbar.setTitle("likes");
                menu.findItem(R.id.item_cal).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.item_edit).setVisible(false);
                break;
            case R.id.mlogout:
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MaccabiDrawerHome.this);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Logout");
                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout");
                alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

                alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("YES", this);
                alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("NO", this);

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();


                return true;
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                    replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).
                    commit();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
            mDrawer.closeDrawers();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        switch (which) {
            case BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                mSharedPreference.clearData();
                startActivity(new Intent(MaccabiDrawerHome.this, MacaabiEmailHome.class));
                break;

            case BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                dialog.dismiss();
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        this.menu = menu;
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menutoolbar, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;

            case R.id.item_edit:
                menu.findItem(R.id.item_edit).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.item_cal).setVisible(true);
                toolbar.setTitle("Edit Profile");
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new FragEditProfile()).commit();
                return true;

            case R.id.item_cal:
                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                        populateSetDate(year, month + 1, dayOfMonth);
                    }
                }, currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay);
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, currentYear - 4);
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, currentMonth);
                datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

                datePickerDialog.setCancelable(false);
                datePickerDialog.show();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    /* populateSetDate method is used
       to display the data in a textView
       in edit profile fragment*/

    public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        TextView dob = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dob);
        dob.setText(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);


        String a1 = getAge(year, month, day);
        TextView agess = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.age);
        agess.setText(a1);
    }

    /* getAge method is used to calculate
       the age and then store in a textView
       in edit profile fragment*/

    private String getAge(int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

        dob.set(year, month, day);

        int age = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dob.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        if (today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < dob.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) {
            age--;
        }

        Integer ageInt = new Integer(age);
        String ageS = ageInt.toString();
        Log.d("age", "getAge: " + ageS);
        return ageS;

    }
    public  void  newcountFrag(){
        Fragment fragment;
        fragment = new FragLikes();
        toolbar.setTitle("likes");
        menu.findItem(R.id.item_cal).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.item_edit).setVisible(false);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new FragLikes()).commit();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `onBackPressed()` method available in activity and fragment to alter the default behavior. Not that it is called for fragment at first and only go to activities method only if it returns false.

Comment: from this code im able to go to the the main fragment.
but after that fragment if i again press the back it should exit